# preserving printed circuit boards

Tags: pcb-fabrication

How can we preserve Printed Circuit Boards without causing any damage to the boards in any conditions (air, cold, heat) while we are not using them for a long time?

Comment: It is not clear whether you are referring to bare circuit boards, or whole completed circuit board assemblies.  That makes a significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you vacuum pack them with some desiccants in side.  Or in other words put the boards in a bag, throw in some moisture absorber packets (same stuff you see in vitamins that says do not eat). Then suck all the air out of it then seal it off.  I suppose if you were fancy maybe nitrogen would work too.

Also different finishes have longer shelf life, hasl or tin is not so great, silver immersion is better maybe you can get 6 months out of that, and then gold enig will probably give you a year or more.   But sealing them up will be the best.  Your manufacturer should be able to do it for you if you don't have a vacuum sealer.

Comment: Only 6 months from HASL!?  Someone forgot to tell the miriad of electronic device all around us that they are only supposed to last 6 months in good storage, let alone ordinary use.

Comment: He's asking about bare pcbs not finished goods.   It's a question of reliable soldering when going through reflow.

Comment: I can see your point for bare boards, but it's not clear at all that is what the OP is asking about.  A "board" can mean a bare board or a fully assembled board, depending on context.  No such context was provided.

Comment: I can see what you are saying however generally a "Printed Circuit Board" means the bare pcb.   A printed circuit assembly, or printed circuit board assembly would be the whole product.  Not that engineers don't get lazy and interchange them sometimes.